# How do use the async function in Es6

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a beginner learner in react. I want to use async-await in the userEffect hook. But I face a syntext problem and I can't solve it.

code:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    checkLogin=async()=>{
      await checkUserLogin=()=>{
        if(sessionStorage.getItem('username')==null){
          loggedIn = false
        }
        else{
          loggedIn = true
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

My error is:

```
./src/component/my_router.jsx
SyntaxError: /home/mnt/project/react_js/todo-list/src/component/my_router.jsx: Invalid left-hand side in assignment expression. (24:6)

  22 |     console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('username'))
  23 |     checkLogin=async()=>{
> 24 |       await checkUserLogin=()=>{
     |       ^
  25 |         if(sessionStorage.getItem('username')==null){
  26 |           loggedIn = false
  27 |         }
```

I want to check session storage at the first start of my dom. How do I check it? Please help me...

Comment: You can try this approach for user authentication: https://usehooks.com/useAuth/

Comment: What does `console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('username'))` return?

Comment: And. what is the syntax problem? The `useEffect` is missing a dependency array. Oh, I see, what is `await () => { ....` doing, or what are you trying to do here? What do you want this effect to be?

Comment: If I had to guess, I think your function could be written as `const checkLogin = () => !!sessionStorage.getItem('username');`.

Comment: FYI, sessionStorage is synchronous so there's nothing really to wait for inside your `useEffect` callback. Are you just wanting to write it out using `async/await` for practice?

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> ./src/component/my_router.jsx
> SyntaxError: /home/mnt/project/react_js/todo-list/src/component/my_router.jsx:
> Invalid left-hand side in assignment expression. (24:6)
>
>   22 |     console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('username'))
>   23 |     checkLogin=async()=>{
> > 24 |       await checkUserLogin=()=>{
>      |       ^
>   25 |         if(sessionStorage.getItem('username')==null){
>   26 |           loggedIn = false
>   27 |         }
> ```

Here it looks like you're trying to do some asynchronous declaration.

```
await checkUserLogin = () => {
```

But this OFC isn't valid syntax.

I suspect you meant to declare `checkUserLogin` as an `async` function, or you are trying to await the session storage. Since [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) isn't asynchronous there's nothing to wait for, you can simply access the value.

```
useEffect(() => {
  checkLogin = () => {
    if(sessionStorage.getItem('username') === null){
      loggedIn = false;
    } else{
      loggedIn = true;
    }
  }

  checkLogin();
}, []);
```

Since `checkLogin` also doesn't need to wait for asynchronous code you can just place the logic in the `useEffect`'s callback body.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(sessionStorage.getItem('username') === null){
    loggedIn = false;
  } else{
    loggedIn = true;
  }
}, []);
```

Or more succinctly

```
useEffect(() => {
  loggedIn = !!sessionStorage.getItem('username');
}, []);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using async on useEffect itself should be avoided.

Instead you should create your async-await function outside the useEffect hook and then trigger it inside.

Something like this:

```
const fetchToken = useCallback(async () => {
    let response = await getAccessTokenSilently();
    setToken(response);
  }, [getAccessTokenSilently]);

useEffect(()=>{
 fetchToken()
  },[fetchToken])
```

Comment: Why should `async` functions be avoided in `useEffect` callback? It's valid.

Comment: I didn't write inside I wrote on, which means directly like useEffect(asnyc () => {})

Comment: Ok, OP didn't do that though so it's a little unclear what question you're answering.

Comment: TBH he seemed clueless so I though I'd just explain it from the begining

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use directly Async await call in useEffect like this, In order to achieve this approach you have to use it like that.

```
useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('username'))
       async function checkUserLogin() {
          checkLogin()
        }
        checkUserLogin();
  },[])

const checkLogin = async() =>{
 await ()=>{
        if(sessionStorage.getItem('username')==null){
          loggedIn = false
        }
        else{
          loggedIn = true
        }
      }
}
```

OR like this

```
useEffect(() => {
    (async() => {
        try {
             await ()=>{
                 if(sessionStorage.getItem('username')==null){
                     loggedIn = false
                  }
                 else{
                     loggedIn = true
                  }
             }
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        }
    })();
}, []);
```

Comment: This isn't true, you can create `async` functions in the `useEffect` callback.

Comment: When you use an async function like, it returns a promise and useEffect doesn't expect the callback function to return Promise, rather it expects that nothing is returned or a function is returned.

Comment: Read OP's code again, it ***isn't*** `useEffect(async () => {....`, which implicitly returns a Promise and is invalid.

Comment: I want to use Es6

Answer (score 1):

You can define and call function in useEffect only

```
 useEffect(() => {
   const myFunc= async()=> {
      // now you can use await in this
      let response = await fetch('URL')
      response = await response.json()
      dataSet(response)
    }

    myFunc()
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define your function like this:-

```
useEffect(()=>{
   const chechUserLogin = async() => {
       const checkLogin = () => new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        if(sessionStorage.getItem('username')==null){
         loggedIn = false;
         reject(loggedIn);
        }
        else{
         loggedIn = true;
         resolve(loggedIn);
        }
       });
     const result = await checkLogin();//checkLogin must return a promise
     //process result
   }
  checkUserLogin();
},[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve it...

```
useEffect(()=>{
    const checkLogin=async()=>{
      await (()=>{
        if(sessionStorage.getItem('username')==null){
          loggedIn = false
        }
        else{
          loggedIn = true
        }
      })
    }
  })
```